# SQL Update else Insert and select Identity if Insert executed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, c#-4.0

I have an SQL Query where I Update table records, and if the record doesn't exist then I create a new one.

My question is, how do I select the Identity column of the Inserted row or the Updated row?

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
SET OrdersID = @OrdersID, 
    RoomID = @RoomID, 
    ProductID = @ProductID, 
    ProductDocumentDate = @ProductDocumentDate, 
    CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
    CreatedDate = @CreatedDate 
WHERE ID = @ID 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    INSERT INTO ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
        (OrdersID, 
         RoomID, 
         ProductID, 
         ProductDocumentDate, 
         CreatedBy, 
         CreatedDate) 
    VALUES 
        (@OrdersID, 
         @RoomID, 
         @ProductID, 
         @ProductDocumentDate, 
         @CreatedBy, 
         @CreatedDate)
```

Then in C# I execute the query:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(statement, connection);

try
{
    connection.Open();

    foreach (ProductsRoomsOrderLog logItem in log)
    {
        //Set Created Date
        logItem.CreatedDate = createdDate;

        command.Parameters.Clear();
        if (logItem.ID == null)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", logItem.ID);
        }

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrdersID", logItem.OrdersID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomID", logItem.RoomID);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", logItem.ProductID);

        if (logItem.ProductDocumentDate == null)
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDocumentDate", DBNull.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductDocumentDate", logItem.ProductDocumentDate);
        }

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", logItem.CreatedBy);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", logItem.CreatedDate);


        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Get Identity column of inserted item
        string selectIdentityStatement = "SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProductsRoomsOrderLog') FROM ProductsRoomsOrderLog";
        SqlCommand selectIdentityCommand = new SqlCommand(selectIdentityStatement, connection);
        logItem.ID = Convert.ToInt64(selectIdentityCommand.ExecuteScalar());
    } 
}
```

Now notice that I have a select Query that gets the Identity column. Unfortunately this doesn't work as I want because it is always reading the Identity of the last row in my table and not the current row in question (be it the updated row or the inserted row). Simply, it doesn't work when Updating a row, only when Inserting a row.

Can anyone please advise me on how I can execute an Update/Insert query and select the correct row identity? In all honest I only really care about retrieving the identity column if I'm inserting the row.

Many thanks, I really appreciate the time you've taken out to read this.

Comment: if you are getting `@@ROWCOUNT` greater than 0 then your @ID is Updated row else you can use `scope_identity()` to get the newest record from table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to execute `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProductsRoomsOrderLog')` in the same SQL command as the INSERT.

```
UPDATE ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
SET OrdersID = @OrdersID, 
    RoomID = @RoomID, 
    ProductID = @ProductID, 
    ProductDocumentDate = @ProductDocumentDate, 
    CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
    CreatedDate = @CreatedDate 
WHERE ID = @ID 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
        (OrdersID, 
         RoomID, 
         ProductID, 
         ProductDocumentDate, 
         CreatedBy, 
         CreatedDate) 
    VALUES 
        (@OrdersID, 
         @RoomID, 
         @ProductID, 
         @ProductDocumentDate, 
         @CreatedBy, 
         @CreatedDate)

    SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProductsRoomsOrderLog')
END
```

then use `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery` to be able to get its result.

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

becomes

```
object identity = command.ExecuteScalar();  
if (identity is int)
    logItem.ID = (int)identity;
```

Comment: Thank you, this works a treat. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe changing your query to

```
UPDATE ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
SET OrdersID = @OrdersID, 
    RoomID = @RoomID, 
    ProductID = @ProductID, 
    ProductDocumentDate = @ProductDocumentDate, 
    CreatedBy = @CreatedBy, 
    CreatedDate = @CreatedDate 
WHERE ID = @ID 

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ProductsRoomsOrderLog 
        (OrdersID, 
         RoomID, 
         ProductID, 
         ProductDocumentDate, 
         CreatedBy, 
         CreatedDate) 
    VALUES 
        (@OrdersID, 
         @RoomID, 
         @ProductID, 
         @ProductDocumentDate, 
         @CreatedBy, 
         @CreatedDate);

   SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('ProductsRoomsOrderLog') FROM ProductsRoomsOrderLog
  END
ELSE
   SELECT @ID
```

and then executing it as a query that returns a value?

By the way: You could also have a look at the [SQL `MERGE` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) which makes the INSERT/UPDATE logic more straightforward.

Comment: Thank you, this works well. I really appreciate your assistance. Sorry I gave the answer tick to @Doug , he included C# code also. If I could give you both the tick I would as you have the same answers.